Prime distribution in triangular number minus x
I'm experimenting with finding sequences of numbers in which prime numbers occur unusually often or rarely.
I noticed that the sequence of triangular numbers practically does not contain prime numbers. The only prime number found is 3. I used PARI/GP code for this
T(n) = n * (n + 1) / 2;
for(n=1, 500000, if( isprime(T(n)), print1(T(n), ", ")));

But if we analyze triangular numbers minus x, the situation becomes interesting. If this x is fixed and equal to one of the triangular numbers, there will also be a few prime numbers in this sequence. But if you subtract something else, you get a lot of prime numbers. Why is this so? You can check, using this lines of code:
for(n=1, 500000, if( isprime(T(n)-1), print1(T(n)-1, ", "))); # tr
for(n=1, 500000, if( isprime(T(n)-2), print1(T(n)-2, ", ")));
for(n=1, 500000, if( isprime(T(n)-3), print1(T(n)-3, ", "))); # tr
for(n=1, 500000, if( isprime(T(n)-4), print1(T(n)-4, ", ")));
for(n=1, 500000, if( isprime(T(n)-6), print1(T(n)-6, ", "))); # tr
for(n=1, 500000, if( isprime(T(n)-10), print1(T(n)-10, ", "))); # tr
for(n=1, 500000, if( isprime(T(n)-15), print1(T(n)-15, ", "))); # tr
for(n=1, 500000, if( isprime(T(n)-5050), print1(T(n)-5050, ", "))); # tr
for(n=1, 500000, if( isprime(T(n)-5055), print1(T(n)-5055, ", ")));


The problem with $T_{n} -x$ is that it doesn't produce many primes.

That $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ with positive integer $n$ only produces prime $3$ is easy to prove. One of $n$ and $n+1$ is even , so we either have the product of $\frac{n}{2}$ and $n+1$ , both greater than $1$ for $n>2$ or the product of $n$ and $\frac{n+1}{2}$ , both greater than $1$ for $n>1$. So you only need to check the cases $n=1$ and $n=2$.

Note $$\frac{n(n+1)}{2}-\frac{m(m+1)}{2}=\frac{(n-m)(m+n+1)}{2}$$ to understand the few primes if $x$ is itself a triangle number.

Finally, if $k$ is not a triangular number , then $8k+1$ is no perfect square , hence $\frac{x(x+1)}2-k$ is irreducible over $\mathbb Q[X]$ and hence the Bunyakovsky conjecture predicts infinite many primes.
